# Implemet help option(F1) in eclipse RCP plugin application

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Currently, a robo help mechanism is getting used in my eclipse rcp application, but I want to implement eclipse help support.
Please tell me comapative pros n cons of help support plugin provide by eclipse and suggest me some quick links to understand well.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of advantages ...

- You can add context sensitive help by enabling the "?" icon in the lower left corner of dialogs & wizards such that the user can easily view the help content.
- Built in search and indexing
- Easily internationalized
- Each of the plug-in's that you include in your RCP can contribute their own, independent, help.